# Catchy phrase: looking at something from several different perspectives

Tags: idiom-requests, metaphors, catch-phrases, aphorism-requests

What is the catchy phrase or an aphorism, or a buzzword, or an idiom with the meaning of looking at something from several different perspectives?

In particular, I am looking for something that is relevant to the context of measuring something using a range of methods.

For example (maybe not the best example), the outside temperature can be gauged:

- Using a thermometer
- Looking outside the window
- Looking at the weather forecast
- Using your own feeling of warmness/coldness
- Etc.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! Please include an example sentence or two showing how you would like to use the term. This will help folks give you better, more targeted answers (and is technically required for this kind of request). Good luck!

Comment: I am looking to use a catchy phrase in the title of my technical article to attract attention. E.g. [catchy phrase]: quantifying X using ten different methods.

Comment: What about tweaking your own phrasing? A question of perspective--quantifying X using ten different methods.

Comment: @SConroy "A question of perspective" suggests there is a difference depending on which perspective you look form. Whereas the point of my article is that different measures I used converge on (more-or-less) the same results.

Comment: Ah ok. If you write that along with your model sentence in the question, you might get better answers. Do you want something on the lines of 'all roads lead to Rome'?

Comment: What is the phrase supposed to express? That the same thing can be *observed* in different ways or that something can be *done* in different ways? Do you want different methods to affect the result—or do you want the same result regardless of method?

Comment: @SConroy yes, that is kind of along the right lines.

Comment: @JasonBassford (1) *observed* in different ways, (2) the same result regardless of method.

Comment: What about 'the roads to Rome -- quantifying X using ten different perspectives? Or does that preempt your answer -- I mean do you want it to be clear in your heading that the results are all the same?

Comment: @SConroy I think that is an accapteble variant.

Answer (score 1):

**play (all) the angles**   [TFD](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/angle)  idiom

> To make use or take advantage of every means or opportunity one can
>   find in order to reach or attain one's goal.

Comment: Not bad! This is the kind of thing I am looking for, but would be good to see more answers.